# youtube iFrame is blank

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

So, when I try to run this on my demo site,
this is just a blank spot in my webpage.
It is not showing youtube or any site I connect it to.

```
<iframe width="640" height="1400" frameborder="0" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/" name="iFrameSearch">
</iframe>
```

Is there a way to get this working without using the Youtube API? I would strongly prefer not to use the API quite yet.

Comment: You code works fine in my chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome as well. I also forgot to list another part of important information! I am using this to show search data. Basically, I have a search bar that is supposed to look on youtube and display the results in the iFrame I am having a problem displaying.

Comment: There's your problem then. Post all of the relevant code or create a JSFiddle

Comment: add X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN in your header.

Comment: Here is the related code at JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/XgJjg/

Comment: @DouglasHarding Did you find the solution? Please share..

Comment: I never found a solution for it, I just ended up creating my own database of video links.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this problem today, and my problem was HTTP vs HTTPS.

If your page is HTTPS, it will not load the iFrame if it is referencing a un-secure, HTTP site.

Try changing your iFrame to always be HTTPS.

See [Insecure content in iframe on secure page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280665/insecure-content-in-iframe-on-secure-page) for more info.

```
<iframe width="640" height="1400" frameborder="0" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/" name="iFrameSearch">
</iframe>
```

Comment: This was my issue today

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead, works very well for me.

```
<embed
width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```

Comment: Sadly, an embedding will not work with what I am trying to achieve. I updated the issue with more details, because I realized I wasn't as specific as I should have been, my apologies.

Answer (score -3):

```
<iframe width="640" height="1400" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281765/youtube-iframe-embed-auto-play).