# load Insecure content in an iframe on secured page(or ssl ) https:// in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, http, https

I have a iframe in asp.net page.
The page is secured page (ie., https://www.abcd.com)

I have a button in this page. Onclick of this button we have to display an iframe, inthat iframe display a video from an http:// url (it is actually an another url in internet).

Currently we have tried with the url :  http://xyx.com/v.aspx?4343

```
 <iframe width="320" scrolling="no" height="240" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" border="0" allowtransparency="true" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent;" src="http://xyx.com/v.aspx?4343">
```

This is giving an error :

Blocked loading mixed active content - http://xyx.com/v.aspx?4343

Can somebody advise how can I load this url in my secured page?

Have tried with the url //xyx.com/v.aspx?4343, however we are getting resource not found 404 error.

please advise..

Comment: Refer to Ques. [9280665][1], 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280665/insecure-content-in-iframe-on-secure-page

it will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot serve a cross origin insecure iframe when you're hosting a SSL encrypted application. In order to serve iframe content, both the host application and remote applications will have to use SSL encryption or both the host and remote applications will have to use un-encrypted requests.

You can find a more detailed answer at [Stack Overflow Question 9280665](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280665/insecure-content-in-iframe-on-secure-page)