# Iframes within Sharepoint HTTPS Website

Tags: html, security, sharepoint, iframe, https

I have a question involving iframes and wether it is possible to make them work within HTTPS websites?
whenever I insert the HTML-CODE and save it (even before publishing the site) the textbox and button (iframe) disappears.

**The code:**

```
<p>
Wil je graag op de hoogte blijven?    <br />
Schrijf je dan hieronder in</p>

<iframe id="iframe_flxml_form"
src="//www.flexmail.eu/sf-30a11a0b93b7b6ed76aa551e1e60f6b39b"
frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:125px;width:100%"
height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>

<p class='small'>
    <a href='http://www.flexmail.eu' target='_blank'>Powered by Flexmail</a>
</p>
```

The middle part is the part that disappears when saved. I've also tried to change the URL into:

**https://** www.flexmail.eu/sf-30a11a0b93b7b6ed76aa551e1e60f6b39b

- The code is for a Form where you can fill in your Email and subscribe for our newsletter which we send by a third party website [Flexmail](https://www.Flexmail.eu)
- Our site is in HTTPS
- [Flexmail](https://www.Flexmail.eu) is also in HTTPS
- [I also found another topic about this, but couldn't get any help from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280665/insecure-content-in-iframe-on-secure-page)

However i can't seem to find the solution online either or if it is even possible or not?
If one of you would know the solution or could tell me wether if it is possible or not, you would help me alot!

P.S. I don't think changing the site settings is an option as it is the website of the Company i'm doing my internship at and it is important data that our clients share or use on the website info  involving their workers, paychecks etc. so the site has to stay highly secured with the same settings etc. Anyway you could help me to get crazy good feedback!

Thanks in advance,

Regards