# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: iframe, ssl-certificate, chromium, self-signed

IS there a way to trick the server so I don't get this error:

Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate.

I'm pulling an iframe of an html website into another website but I keep getting the console (chrome) error in the title of this question and in internet explorer it says:

Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate.

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to access an insecure resource from a secure resources. I believe they have a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280665/insecure-content-in-iframe-on-secure-page).

Answer (score 303):

Your resource probably use a self-signed SSL certificate over HTTPS protocol.
Chromium, so Google Chrome block by default this kind of resource considered unsecure.

You can bypass this this way :

- Assuming your frame's URL is `https://www.domain.com`, open a new tab in chrome and go to `https://www.domain.com`.
- Chrome will ask you to accept the SSL certificate. Accept it.
- Then, if you reload your page with your frame, you could see that now it works

The problem as you can guess, is that each visitor of your website has to do this task to access your frame.

You can notice that chrome will block your URL for each navigation session, while chrome can memorise for ever that you trust this domain.

If your frame can be accessed by HTTP rather than HTTPS, I suggest you to use it, so this problem will be solved.

Comment: I think when you open the other tab, you need to go to `https://domain.com` and accept the SSL cert.

Comment: @Hozefa Yes, that's it.

Comment: @RémiBecheras, is there any way to get Chrome to remember to trust the certificate over multiple navigation sessions?

Comment: Not in chrome directly. In fact, chromium use the OS certificate management system. If you run on linux, you can trust certificates using certutil CLI : `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n <certificate nickname> -i <certificate filename>` See there : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxCertManagement . If you run another OS, I don't know but others must.

Comment: In order to add a such rule, you have to get the certificate. If it's yours, you already have it. If don't, click the https left icon on adressbar > certificate informations > details > export. Then, use this file

Comment: This also worked for the weird case where a site was sending a request to the same domain (itself) which I had just approved continuing past the self-signed certificate but then Chrome was throwing this error.

Comment: Is there a way to do this kind of bypass through client side code? Meaning, can I program into the client "hey this server you're trying to access looks sketchy, but its ok trust me. I wrote you both, You're technically code brothers/sisters/gender neutral siblings" ?

Comment: @discodane Developping/using a browser plugin, probably. Without that, just in javascript, definitively not.

Comment: @RémiBecheras, so after making it works, how to unaccept the certificate

Comment: This also helped me http://superuser.com/questions/487748/how-to-allow-chrome-browser-to-load-insecure-content

Comment: +1 Just be careful of using HTTP instead of HTTPS. HTTPS confers many security benefits, so make sure you don't need them in your situation before changing to HTTP.

Comment: Bypassing HTTPS is not a great solution. HTTP is unsecure and development should integrate security as a primary element in the normal course of writing code.

Answer (score 33):

Sometimes Google Chrome throws this error, even if it should not.
I experienced it when Chrome had a new version, and it needed to be restarted.
After restarting the same page worked without any errors.
The error in the console was:

```
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

Comment: Confirmed, a restart of Chrome (and killing all the background Chrome processes) fixed it for me.

Comment: doesn't work.. its a self signed certificate.. it won't work by restarting

Comment: Confirmed also with me!

Comment: @Balazs, Is restarting the browser the only way? Assuming we can't afford to restart, is there a way to do it via `chrome://net-internals`?

Comment: A restart of Chrome (without background processes) fixed it for me also. Thanks!

Comment: I was messin' with my system.webServer rewrite rules to redirect to https.  The moment Chrome sees a rewrite to https, it doesn't matter if you remove it or not, Chrome holds onto that information.  So this solution worked.  Just cleared data for localhost and restarted Chrome.

Comment: typically happens when doing regular updates on Linux without restarting the computer for a while

Answer (score 8):

I still experienced the problem described above on an Asus T100 Windows 10 test device for both (up to date) Edge and Chrome browser.

Solution was in the **date/time settings of the device**; somehow the date was not set correctly (date in the past). Restoring this by setting the correct date (and restarting the browsers) solved the issue for me. I hope I save someone a headache debugging this problem.

Comment: I'm encountering a similar error on an asus zenbook running Windows 8. Unfortunately, this didn't work for me but can you explain in more detail how you reset the date/time? Just by setting the time zone through the windows ui?

Comment: @DEls, I switched timezones in Windows configuration - that reset the system clock for me. Did you restart the browser afterwards?
If timing did not solve the problem you might have to look into the other solution described in this topic.

Comment: I don't know why, but this worked for me. The year was set to 2048, changed it to current year and all fixed. Thanks @SebastiaanOrdelman

Answer (score 6):

Offering another potential solution to this error.

If you have a frontend application that makes API calls to the backend, make sure you reference the domain name that the certificate has been issued to.

**e.g.**

```
https://example.com/api/etc
```

**and not**

```
https://123.4.5.6/api/etc
```

In my case, I was making API calls to a secure server with a certificate, but using the IP instead of the domain name. This threw a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`.

Answer (score 6):

open up your console and hit the URL inside. it'll take you to the API page and then in the page accept the SSL certificate, go back to your app page and reload. 
remember that SSL certificates should have been issued for your Dev environment before.

Answer (score 4):

If you're developing, and you're developing with a Windows machine, simply add `localhost` [as a Trusted Site](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BLOivjDTTW0).

And yes, per DarrylGriffiths' comment, although it may look like you're adding an Internet Explorer setting...

> I believe those are Windows rather than IE settings. Although MS tend to assume that they're only IE (hence the alert next to "Enable Protected Mode"  that it requries restarted IE)...

Comment: I am using linux ubuntu, not windows, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to watch for, and report, a possible `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

I was having this issue as well, using a self-signed certificate, which I have chosen not to save into the Chrome Settings. After accessing the https domain and accepting the certificate, the ajax call works fine. But once that acceptance has timed-out or before it has first been accepted, the `jQuery.ajax()` call fails silently: the `timeout` parameter does not seem help and the `error()` function never gets called.

As such, my code never receives a `success()` or `error()` call and therefore hangs. I believe this is a bug in jquery's handling of this error. My solution is to force the `error()` call after a specified timeout.

This code does assume a jquery ajax call of the form `jQuery.ajax({url: required, success: optional, error: optional, others_ajax_params: optional})`.

Note: You will likely want to change the function within the `setTimeout` to integrate best with your UI: rather than calling `alert()`.

```
const MS_FOR_HTTPS_FAILURE = 5000;
$.orig_ajax = $.ajax;
$.ajax = function(params)
{
  var complete = false;
  var success = params.success;
  var error = params.error;
  params.success = function() {
    if(!complete) {
      complete = true;
      if(success) success.apply(this,arguments);
    }
  }
  params.error = function() {
    if(!complete) {
      complete = true;
      if(error) error.apply(this,arguments);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(!complete) {
      complete = true;
      alert("Please ensure your self-signed HTTPS certificate has been accepted. "
        + params.url);
      if(params.error)
        params.error( {},
          "Connection failure",
          "Timed out while waiting to connect to remote resource. " +
          "Possibly could not authenticate HTTPS certificate." );
    }
  }, MS_FOR_HTTPS_FAILURE);

  $.orig_ajax(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of your https that means SSL certification. Try on Localhost.