# No response from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, google-chrome

I am not getting any response from my AJAX call to the API.
Few days back it was working fine and I was getting response JSON but now I am not able to get any JSON object.
Mozilla does not give response JSON but shows no error but in Chrome I am getting net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

AngularJS code:

```
app.controller("LoginCtrl",
        function($scope, $http,$location,$rootScope) {
    $scope.login = function(user){
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://aadvq11nwbv01.staples.com/wcs/resources/v1/member/login?storeId=10101&responseFormat=json",
            /*header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*",*/
            header: "Content-Type: application/json",
            header: "Accept: application/json",
            data:{
                companyID: $scope.user.customerid,
                userID: $scope.user.userid,
                password: $scope.user.password
            }
        })
        .success(function (response){
            $rootScope.profile="xxx";
            userDetails = response;
            console.log(userDetails);
            $location.url("/profile")
        })
        .error(function (err){
            $scope.logerr="err";
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your url has "https" specified. Are you sure your backend has a valid SSL cert and can serve a https request?

Comment: I used the same url few days back and it was working fine....

Comment: Were any changes made to the backend server in the last few days? Did their https certificate expire? Can you access the url like a regular website in chrome and do you see any errors?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your https certificates, I've had this happen to me with self-signed certificates where you have to navigate to the site clicking a button that says something like 'I'm aware of the risks, take me there'  and then the cache is cleared while you remained on the site. Try clearing the cache again, closing the browser and opening it again.

Comment: No nothing as such..I am able to access the API urls via Chrome

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response it might help you.

Comment: @PankajTripathi - Using Fiddler or Postman, can you check the server response to see if the response contains the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header?

Comment: yvesmancera I did the same but it sill doesn't work

Comment: @user1 I am getting this response header via Swagger UI for APIs  {
  "date": "Fri, 07 Aug 2015 17:17:32 GMT",
  "server": "IBM_HTTP_Server/7.0.0.27 (Unix)",
  "vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent",
  "content-encoding": "gzip",
  "p3p": "policyref=\"http://qa11.staplesadvantage.com/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\"",
  "keep-alive": "timeout=4, max=1000",
  "connection": "Keep-Alive",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "content-language": "en-US"
}

Comment: Based on that header listing, it looks like Access-Control-Allow-Origin isn't there. I can only guess it was there before, but I can indeed say that's your problem.

Comment: I added  Access-Control-Allow-Origin when I was getting CORS related issues. But now even that isn't working

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be you have specified in wrong way. `header` should be an object then define its properties in it.

**Code**

```
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://aadvq11nwbv01.staples.com/wcs/resources/v1/member/login?storeId=10101&responseFormat=json",
        header: {
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json"
        },
        data:{
            companyID: $scope.user.customerid,
            userID: $scope.user.userid,
            password: $scope.user.password
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error is that the SSL certificate provided by the webserver is not recognised and therefore not trusted. If you are using a self-signed certificate on your webserver this will explain it. Otherwise there is an issue with the setup of your certificate.