# Getting ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE when trying to use IIS ssl

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ssl, iis

I am trying to implement my site with SSL. I used the IIS to create a self-signed certificate. But when calling the site using https I keep getting ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE and never seem to reach the server.
I use Chrome extension 'Advanced Rest client' to call the server.
I have no clue to what to do, appreciate the help...

Comment: Have you attempted to connect a normal browser connection.  Does it only fail when using the rest client?

Comment: @chief7 I've tried it also from a chrome extension I have and same result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_INSECURE\_RESPONSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response)

Answer (score 1):

Recreate the self signed certificate using the following tutorial -

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx

I've never seen this error specifically but suspect there is an issue with the certificate.