# Application not loading when deployed to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

i'm new to web development and i've created an application that i would like to deploy to firebase. i referred to the online resources and carried out the necessary steps (as shown below) to get my application online. now when i got to my site i don't see the data loading. I recieve the foll error. Now even if i remove the 'scroll to top' script referenced in the error, there is no data loading.

```
GET https://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow88.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

I am walking you through my workflow if that's all right. Any help would be appreciated.

The foll is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.0",
    "angular": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.18",
    "mdi": "^1.4.57",
    "angular-material": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

the foll is my firebase.json

```
    {
  "firebase": "xxx",
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*"

  ]
}
```

It think it may be worthwhile to mention that i don't recieve a blank page When i run the application on a local http-server. the application loads and i get all the data from firebase without any errors.

Thanks

Comment: It seems your site is loading an insecure resource: `https://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow88.js`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response. If you open that URL in Chrome, you'll see a clear warning about its certificate.

Comment: But Frank even if remove the reference to that resource, i still find nothing loading.

Comment: But this error message should disappear when you remove the reference: `GET https://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow88.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Comment: @Frank all righty.. i will do that again.. but i've tried it earlier; the error does not show , but the page still does not load. so i'm thinking its got to do with something else as well.

Comment: The error you got is caused by the fact that `https://arrow.scrolltotop.com/arrow88.js` is serving from an invalid certificate. There might be other problems too, but the cause of this one is without question.

Comment: @Frank so ive removed reference to the script; but the page is not loading; i don't get any errors as well. what cld i be missing here? `https://ngmasters.firebaseapp.com/`

Comment: Frank, i was checking the console for both the local host and the firebase url:

In the former, under 'Network', i have classfied.tpl.html showing whereas in the latter, the template does not show.

Is it because i am using state provider in my application and that state is not getting resolved in the firebase url?

My state is as follows:

`$stateProvider
.state('masters', {
url: '/masters',
templateUrl: 'components/classifieds.tpl.html',
controller: 'classifiedsCtrl' 

});`

Comment: aah.. it works now.. yes i was missing the url for the state.