# calling iframe showing error net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have an iframe in which I call a [login page of external website](https://www.login.externalwebsite.com) and its working fine.. but when I enter user credentials login inside the iframe. it will redirect to user dashboard and iframe don't show any thing and through error below

> Refused to display 'https://www.dashboard.externalwebsite.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
>
> CSSLogin.aspx:83 GET https://www.dashboard.externalwebsite.com/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_INSECURE\_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin/33777934#33777934

Comment: do you have solution?

Comment: Thank you, you may continue your work now..

Comment: @VDWWD both the websites are of same domain. How was user able to embed one of them in iFrame but not the other ? Assuming both the websites are indeed in the same domain. I thought X-Frame-Options is set on domain level

Comment: how to set X-Frame options?