# Express HTTPS response (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE)

Tags: node.js, express, https

I get `'net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE'` (getting `HTTP` back) when making requests to my `HTTPS` API. The Express documentation seems a bit sparse on this. Maybe I'm missing somewhat about the fairly fundamental here?

I'd like to send `HTTPS` and respond with `HTTPS`

```
let app = express()

app.get('/climbers/:latitude/:longitude', (req, res) => {
    const loc = { latitude: req.params.latitude, longitude: req.params.longitude }
    const nearbyClimbers = climbers.filter(climber => haversine(climber, loc) < 5)

    res.json(nearbyClimbers)
})

let secureServer = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/server.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca.crt'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
}, app)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this *was* returning `HTTPS`, I just misunderstood `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25075349/1340046

I had dealt with this error for the static resources coming from another port (`webpack dev server`). What I didn't realize was that I'd need to confirm the `ssl` exception for the API separately. All I had to do was visit the API url through my browser and confirm the exception.

Another option would be to add the personal ssl certificate