# BitMovin throwing (ERRO_INSEURE_RESPONSE) error

Tags: jquery

I have used bitmovin player version 8.29.0 for lg webos and tizen platform, but recently my player not working and getting this type of error (ERRO_INSEURE_RESPONSE), I also used latest version but getting same error.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of this behaviour could be related to the SSL certificate [1] of the source stream the player is trying to fetch. Could you reproduce it in our sample app [2] as well ?

Please feel free to contact our Support team at support@bitmovin.com and to submit more details such as your stream URL. We will then get back to you shortly.

[1] [Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688565/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-insecure-response)

[2] https://github.com/bitmovin/bitmovin-player-tizen-demo