# Bootstrap Modals not showing PDF Document after Close and re-Show

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have Problem when trying to make Bootstrap Modals to show PDF Document using `<embed src="./pdfFiles.pdf"></embed>` Tag. I am using Bootstrap Version 4.5

When user click the button to trigger the modals,  Bootstrap modals normally displays PDF document. But, The problem appear when user **close** the modals and **show** it again. instead of displaying PDF Document, modals displays blank document.

[image: Blank Document on Bootstrap Modals after close and re show]

**EDITED**
My Code Shown below.
**Bootstrap CDN**

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<title>PDF Show</title>
```

**Show the modal**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Launch modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">PDF Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <embed src="http://localhost/pdfFile.pdf"></embed>
            <embed src="http://192.168.0.13/pdfFile.pdf"></embed>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already contained the issue, The PDF Failed to display only when I use the IP address (or `base_url()` in Codeigniter) to fill pdf link in `src="http://192.168.0.1/pdfFile.pdf"`
No problem appear when I use `http://localhost/pdfFile.pdf`

```
<embed src="http://localhost/pdfFile.pdf"></embed>
<embed src="http://192.168.0.1/pdfFile.pdf"></embed>
```

Comment: Please provide the code, where and how you show and close the modal.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i already put my code above, i am using bootstrap modal to show and close the modal

Comment: Then your issue might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280665/insecure-content-in-iframe-on-secure-page). You can't include a non-secure url in your html, when using https. AFAIR localhost is an exception in most browsers.